# How to make a linear-gradient to fulfill two-coloured body in CSS

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to make that in CSS to my webpage:
[image: linear-gradient]

But the only thing I get is a repeated gradient over all page:
[image: Don't know why]

This is the code I'm using:

```css
body {
  background: @body-color;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#999cdb, #f6bdbd);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#999cdb, #f6bdbd);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#999cdb, #f6bdbd);
  background: linear-gradient(#999cdb, #f6bdbd);
}
```

That might be a simple thing, but I don't know what I am missing.

Comment: Like this https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1235/?

Comment: What do you mean by "to fulfill two-colored body?"

Comment: Awesome gradient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to specify a height. Use vh which simply means viewport height which is the height of the user's visible area of a web page. That way it would cover the entire height of the screen no matter the device.

The background-attachment property sets whether a background is fixed or scrolls with the rest of the page.

```css
body {
  background: @body-color;

background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#999cdb, #f6bdbd);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#999cdb, #f6bdbd);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#999cdb, #f6bdbd);
  background: linear-gradient(#999cdb, #f6bdbd);
  height: 100vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: Yeah, but know whenever my page grows verticaly, the lnear-gradient will be repeated!

Comment: @wagnerdelima I forgot something... I edited the answer. I added background-attachment: fixed; which would do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this :

```css
body {
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom,rgba(153,156,219,1) 0%,rgba(246,189,189,1) 60%);
    height:100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
}
```

Comment: I made my solution made by a combination of all of yours! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

So there you are:

```css
body{
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F4F4F4 50%, #FFE0DA 50%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 200px;
}
```

How it works:

1. `to bottom` specifies that the gradient flows from top to bottom.
2. You should specify the `color-stop` in percentages - here `#F4F4F4` stops at 50% and then at 50% `#FFE0DA` starts. So you get a *two-color div* without any gradient effect.

To get the gradient effect, just vary the `color-stop`s:

```css
body{
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #F4F4F4 10%, #FFE0DA 50%);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  height: 200px;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: @wagnerdelima added in the explanation... Thanks!

Comment: whenever my page height changes, the linear-gradient will repeat. If I put no-repeat, there will be a blank area.

Comment: try changing height- if you have given `background-repeat: no-repeat` that won't happen...